# Is there a global storage in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is there a global storage in Guild Wars 2 like in Guild War where all your characters have access to it? It seems like a functionality that would naturally be there but I have yet to find it yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The major cities each provide access to a bank which is 30 slots (you can increase this) shared by all characters on your account.

You need to either travel to a bank manually or use one of the Freemium items that allow bank access from the middle of anywhere.

Additionally, your collections storage of crafting materials (max 250 of each crafting material) is global to your account -- and you can access that (and your bank) from any crafting station.

Comment: Hmm do you know what the icon the banks have on the map?

Comment: @Jay the bank in divinity is on the second level near the city center in case you can't find it

Comment: Also remember to right click your materials and click 'send to collection' to automatically store them in your materials storage!

Comment: It's also worth nothing that you can get access to your bank from any crafting station.

Comment: another tip. You can form your own personal guild (costs 1 silver) and have your characters in there (remember to 'represent' the guild). After you accumulate like 600 guild points or so, you get your own personal guild bank!  (you can be in up to 5 guilds at the same time so you don't have to leave your guild for this, just 'represent' your guild, log in with all your characters every day for 10 guild points each. Then you can represent your normal guild again)

Comment: @Rodolfo: sorry, but that's incorrect. To build your own guild storage, you need to get 2500 influence - 500 to get to architecture level 1, 1000 to get to level 2, and 1000 to build the 50-slot vault. Also, there is no limit on how many guilds you can belong to - though each character can of course only represent one guild at a time. And finally, you won't get 10 points per character per day consistently. I'm not sure what the exact algorithm is, but there are limits on how many characters get those 10 points and there are multiple conditions on whether you can get them.

Comment: @aaamos I haven't played in many months but what you had to do to get the 10 points per character per day was basically to represent your personal guild for the characters and log in as each of them daily. It does take a while, when I wrote the post I didn't know about the 3 'cash in' steps so yes, it won't happen in a week, but if you do it every day, you'll eventually get it in a couple of months.